# Building includes map using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hi I have a simple database, and what I am trying to do is build simple include maps as string using eager loading mechanism in EF CORE.

So in other words mu db models looks like:

[image]

And models that are supporting them:

```
public class StartTable
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<TableA> TableA {get; set;}
    public ICollection<TableB> TableA {get; set;}
}

public class TableA
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    public StartTable StartTable {get; set;}
    public int StartTableId {get; set;}
    
    public TableAChild TableAChild {get; set;}
    public int TableAChildId {get; set;}
    
    public TableAB TableAB {get; set;}
    public int TableABId {get; set;}
}

public class TableB
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    public StartTable StartTable {get; set;}
    public int StartTableId {get; set;}
    
    public TableBChild TableBChild {get; set;}
    public int TableBChildId {get; set;}
    
    public TableAB TableAB {get; set;}
    public int TableABId {get; set;}
}

public class TablAChild
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public TableA TableA {get; set;}
}

public class TableBChild
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public TableB TableB {get; set;}
}

public class TableAB
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public TableA TableA {get; set;}
    public TableB TableB {get; set;}
}
```

I think relations are readible from models. Now I just want to create a map, that is I want to select start table and with include of all branches so final include path should looks like:

```
_context.StartTable.Include("StartTable.TableA.TableAChild")
_context.StartTable.Include("StartTable.TableA.TableAB")
_context.StartTable.Include("StartTable.TableB.TableBChild")
_context.StartTable.Include("StartTable.TableB.TableAB")
```

And If I type this manually it works, but this will grow a lot so I don't want to update this every time something will come up, I tried AutoInclute() in context on main table but it includes only 1 level down.

I thought I can create some sort of map function that looks like:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> BuildIncludeTree(DbContext context, Type type)
{
    var entityAssemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().SelectMany(assembly => Assembly.Load(assembly).GetTypes());
    
    void AddAssetByString(ref HashSet<string> navigation, List<string> createdPaths)
    {
        foreach (var path in createdPaths)
        {
            var splitPath = path.Split('.');
            var relationNavigationNode = splitPath.Last();
            var parentNavigationType = entityAssemblyTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == relationNavigationNode);
            
            if (parentNavigationType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown type parent: {relationNavigationNode}");
            }

            var parentNodesProperties = 
                parentNavigationType.GetProperties().Where(prop => !prop.PropertyType.IsSimple() && !splitPath.Contains(prop.Name)).ToArray();
            if (!parentNodesProperties.Any())
            {
                navigation.Add(path);
                continue;
            }
            navigation.Add(path);
            AddAssetByString(ref navigation, parentNodesProperties.Select(prop => $"{path}.{prop.Name}").ToList());
        }
    }
    
    IEntityType entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(type);
    if (entityType == null) throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown entity type {type.Name}");
    
    var navigationsByString = new HashSet<string>();
    var relationsByString = entityType.GetNavigations().Select(nav => $"{type.Name}.{nav.Name}");
    AddAssetByString(ref navigationsByString, relationsByString.ToList());

    return new List<string>();
}
```

But problem here is relation to TableAB, I mean when I get to mapping this part function goes circular and creates map:

```
StartTable.TableA.TableAChild.TableB.StartTable.TableA ... and so on
```

Can this be prevented and what am I missing?
Can EF Core detect in some sort of way navigation downwards and upwards?
Or is there any other and simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't Include all .There is already post about that here
[Is there a way to Include() all with dbcontext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28482882/is-there-a-way-to-include-all-with-dbcontext)
But if correctly understand you can use `Linq` to make you code shorter like:

```
_context.StartTable.Include(x => x.TableA.TableAChild && x.TableA.TableAB && x. ....)
```

And in that case you will need to add entities you want to include in your class also you can use `[NotMapped]` attribute if you working direct with your class instead of dto. So in that way you can access the mapped entities direct from the class like `class.TableAChild`

```
+
public virtual TableAChild TableAChild { get; set; }
public virtual TableAB TableAB { get; set; }
```

Greetings and good luck